# Whats the difference between Invalidate and OnPaint

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

In my Winforms application, I want to send a Paint request.

Which method should I use? Also, what's the basic difference between `Invalidate` and `OnPaint` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnPaint is the method where the actual painting takes place.

Invalidate is a way of requesting that the control or form be repainted.

[Whats the difference between Control.Invalidate, Control.Update and Control.Refresh?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/subhagpo/archive/2005/02/22/378098.aspx)

Comment: Invalidate puts a rectangle in a queue of areas to be painted.  If 5 rectangles are in the queue, they are combined so overlapping areas only get painted once.